# Perfomance question about share (or not) fields CCK in lots of content types

Tags: entities

I am working in Drupal 6.x.  I have approximately 50 content types.  All content types have common fields CCK.  Each content type has approximately 25 fields.  Is better share the common fields CCK or is better to make the fields for each content type?

These content types are used for views.

In terms of performance, resource consumption, what is the better option?

Thanks to all for your ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question, but if a lot of your content types are very similar, you might want to use taxonomy to separate them. This way you have fewer content types, and you can still use views by filtering on taxonomy terms. The UI would probably be easier to create an "Automobile" and tag it as a type "Car" than scrolling through a list of content type to create a "Car" directly. Just some thoughts.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of 
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/does-having-too-many-content-types-negatively-affect-site-speed-and-performance

Comment: @landing I disagree, I think that could not be related, someone can have several content types and some of this content types without CCK fields.

Comment: @moon.watcher I guess the question I linked to isn't really a duplicate, but the answers provided may have some insight into site performance when it comes to using a lot of cck fields with views. Credit to David Meister for pointing out that building a view to output shared fields will make your queries less efficient.

Comment: @landing yes, I agree, there are answers related.